# How to redirect user after login to the same page in which he was

Tags: drupal-7

have a cart products page, if a person clicks on a product add to cart button they will be redirected to the login page.

After a successful login, I need to send the user back to same products page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
function module_user_login(&$edit, $account) {  
  $alias = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);  
  if (in_array('Member', $account->roles)) {  
    drupal_goto("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $alias);  
  }  
}
```

Note that the code above checks that the user has the Role ‘Member’.

Or make use of this [module](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination)

Comment: The OP wants to redirect users to the product page they were watching before being redirected to the login page. `$_GET['q']` contains the path for the currently shown page, not for the page the users were watching before being redirected to the login page.